# How to use 1000hz.github.io validator

Tags: forms, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

Please provide me with a complete example of what to download, what to link and how to use it in a form for the title above. I have searched and found no basic documentation for newbie. Please help. [source site](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/)

Comment: The documentation is right on the source site you linked.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to make sure that you are using [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/) to make use of the Bootstrap Validator plugin. The full instructions for getting started with Bootstrap are [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/).

Assuming that you are using Bootstrap, you then need to download the appropriate JS file from GitHub [here](https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator). The JS file that you'll actually need to make your form work is either the minified `validator.min.js` file or the more readable `validator.js` file, both of which are available from the `/dist` directory at the GitHub link above. Then, just include that JS file as a script in the HTML page where your form is, i.e. something like `<script src="js/validator.min.js"></script>`

Finally, build your form using Bootstrap. There is full documentation on how to create Bootstrap forms [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms). Once you've created your form using Bootstrap, you can add in the Bootstrap Validator functionality just as shown in the examples and usage instructions on your [source site](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/).

Comment: # james thanks why such excellent answer provided by you is not given for newbies there. For example in small steps. Can you provide me similarly how to install the jquery validator from jquery validation site.

Comment: sir can you provide how to make work the example given in the site i did as you said but i what above the code for validation. I am new pls help

Comment: I've not used the jQuery Validation myself so have not performed the installation steps. But it looks like their site provide a download link on their [home page](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) and [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) link. If you're new to jQuery I recommend the [W3Schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/) first. The validator should make sense once you've got your teeth into that.